# Thread local storage define in assembly

Tags: assembly, thread-local-storage

I define a thread local storage in assembly,

```
  " .LOCALMAP:\n"
  "   .section .tbss,\"awT\",@nobits\n"
  "   .type  LOCALMAP,@object\n"
  "   .size LOCALMAP,8\n"
  "   .zero 8\n"
```

as get errors:
"attempt to store non-empty string in section `.tbss'" ? why those error occurs?

btw,i creat thread local storage in assembly into afl afl-as.h for some use.

Comment: Did you switch the section back? Which line causes the error? You know bss is for zeroes? (see also `@nobits`)

Comment: Is this inline assembly?  You cannot just switch sections in inline assembly.  If you must, switch there and then back with `.pushsection` and `.popsection`.  Note that you can replace this with just `static _Thread_local char LOCALMAP[8];`.

Comment: Not to mention that the label should be inside the section otherwise it will refer to the current section.

Comment: not inline，afl specific as through -B parameter ,the afl-as.h will insert into .s file directly.  I put the LOCALMAP aflter .section ,still the errors.    
   "  .section .tbss,\"awT\",@nobits\n"
  "   .LOCALMAP:\n"
  "   .type  LOCALMAP,@object\n"
  "   .size LOCALMAP,8\n"
  "   .zero 8\n"  
I define  __thread int count ,  I used gcc -S to get assembly , see blew:
 .file "local_thread.c"
 .text
 .globl count
 .section .tbss,"awT",@nobits
 .align 4
 .type count, @object
 .size count, 4
count:
 .zero 4
I am not familiar with assembly,pls tell me if explanation isn't clear